# parallel vector field geodesic parallel coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

> Let $X$ be a parallel vector field along the curve $\gamma$. $X(s)=cos(\phi(s))x_1(y^1(s),y^2(s))+\frac{sin(\phi(s))}{h}x_2(y^1(s),y^2(s))$
>   
> $x:U\rightarrow M$ is a surface and the metric tensor is given by $g_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0\\
> 0 & h^2
> \end{pmatrix}
> \;\;$ ($h\gt0$)
>   
>   Prove that $\dot\phi(s)=-h_1(y^1(s),y^2(s))\dot y^2(s)$
>   Note: $\gamma(s)=x(y^1(s),y^2(s))$ is curve in $M$.
>   Let $ R$ be a polygon bounded by $\gamma$

I did find the solution to the first part but my follow up questions would be, what is the connection between the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$ and $\phi(s)$ ?

Comment: Have you calculated the Christoffel symbols and written down the differential equations that the components of a vector field must satisfy if it is parallel along a curve?

Comment: Can you please clarify what each of these quantities are?  Presumably $(y^1, y^2) \in U$ are linear coordinates, $(x_1, x_2)$ are local coordinates in $M$, but what is the relationship between $\gamma, \phi$, and $h$?  What is the dependence of $h$ on the location in the manifold?

Comment: @Mnifldz: No, $x_i$ is shorthand for $\partial x/\partial y^i$. $h$ is a smooth function on the surface, $\gamma$ and $\phi$ are functions of $s$. I agree that the OP should have made things a bit clearer, but ... Similarly, $h_1 = \partial h/\partial y^1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I did find the solution but I got a follow up question (What is the connnection of the geodesic curver of $\gamma$ and $\phi(s)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've arrived at a vector field $X$ that is parallel along $\gamma$. You need to look at the angle $\psi$ between $X$ and $\dot\gamma$  and see at what rate it is changing. That is, $\dot\psi$ will be the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$, assuming that $\gamma$ is arclength-parametrized.

Comment: Could you explain why the geodesic curvature is the rate of change of the angle between $\dot \gamma$ and $X$ ?

Comment: What is your definition of geodesic curvature? Why not start with that and do the computation?